# Apache web server - equivalent of apxs for windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, apxs2

I am trying to install a module on my apache web server on Windows.
In order to build it, I need the tool apxs but in **[HOME_APACHE]\bin** there is no such tool.

How can I do that on my windows 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is downloadable for Apache2.2 here. README includes install instructions.

https://www.apachelounge.com/download/additional/

Comment: thanks, does it works on win 64bit and on apache 2.4?